# The for loop function is not running

Tags: javascript

I was making a color flipper but my code is not running. another file with same code is working well which I downloaded from git. please help for loop function is not working and I am not getting any errors in console as well.

```
const hex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const color = document.querySelector(".color");
btn.addEventListener = ("click", function() {
  let hexcolor = "#";
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    hexcolor += hex[getrandomnumber()];
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexcolor;
  color.textcontent = hexcolor;
});

function getrandomnumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length)
};
```

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Check the console for errors.

Comment: @rayhatfield I don't think that typo will cause an error message.

Comment: The code is syntactically valid, it just doesn't do what they want. It's going to be interpreted as an assignment and `"click", function() ...` will be interpreted as a comma operator.

Comment: Ah. Right. Yep yep.

Answer (score 2):

You used an `=` instead of calling `addEventListener`.

```js
const hex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const color = document.querySelector(".color");
//                   ↓ here
btn.addEventListener = ("click", function() {
  let hexcolor = "#";
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    hexcolor += hex[getrandomnumber()];
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexcolor;
  color.textcontent = hexcolor;
});

function getrandomnumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length)
};
```

To clarify this: This *overwrote* the addEventListener property on the button with the handler function, since JavaScript has a comma operator that evaluates to the last value (in this case the function ). Since this is valid syntax and just doesn't do what you wanted, it doesn't show up in the console.

Comment: It is working. Thank you